# How to convert character of percent into numeric in R

Tags: r, character, numeric, r-faq

I have data with percent signs (%) that I want to convert into numeric. I run into a problem when converting character of percentage to numeric. E.g. I want to convert "10%" into 10%, but

```
as.numeric("10%")
```

returns `NA`. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

10% is per definition not a numeric vector. Therefore, the answer NA is correct. You can convert a character vector containing these numbers to numeric in this fashion:

```
percent_vec = paste(1:100, "%", sep = "")
as.numeric(sub("%", "", percent_vec))
```

This works by using sub to replace the % character by nothing.

Answer (score 34):

Remove the `"%"`, convert to numeric, then divide by 100.

```
x <- c("10%","5%")
as.numeric(sub("%","",x))/100
# [1] 0.10 0.05
```

Answer (score 27):

If you're a `tidyverse` user (and actually also if not) there's now a `parse_number` function in the `readr` package:

```
readr::parse_number("10%")
```

The advantage is generalization to other common string formats such as:

```
parse_number("10.5%")
parse_number("$1,234.5")
```

Comment: I really enjoy all the old SO questions that now have sexy Tidyverse solutions.

Comment: readr::parse_number("10%") produces '10' - the number here is 0.1 - tidyverse might be sexy but would help if it really works too:)

Comment: This also doesn't work when `x` is already a number. I need my function to handle percents or numeric columns (depending on which column is being plotted). `readr::parse_number("-10.5")` yields `-10.5` (should be `-0.105`) and`readr::parse_number(-10.5)` returns an error. Two downvotes for this solution.

Comment: @Dannid (a) why should `readr::parse_number("-10.5")` return `-0.105` and not `-10.5`, it is a general function for parsing numbers (b) the function takes a "Character vector of values to parse", so `readr::parse_number(-10.5)` results in a bad input error, makes sense.

Comment: Hi @GioraSimchoni it looks like I mistyped. For the first example I should have included the percent sign: `readr::parse_number("-10.5%")` should return `-0.105` rather than `-10.5`

Answer (score 8):

Get rid of the extraneous characters first:

```
topct <- function(x) { as.numeric( sub("\\D*([0-9.]+)\\D*","\\1",x) )/100 }
my.data <- paste(seq(20)/2, "%", sep = "")
> topct( my.data )
 [1] 0.005 0.010 0.015 0.020 0.025 0.030 0.035 0.040 0.045 0.050 0.055 0.060 0.065 0.070 0.075 0.080
[17] 0.085 0.090 0.095 0.100
```

(Thanks to Paul for the example data).

This function now handles: leading non-numeric characters, trailing non-numeric characters, and leaves in the decimal point if present.

Comment: It's more complex because it strips out anything non-numeric that follows the numbers....

Comment: Edited to make it handle preceeding characters as well, and to make it a function that you can re-use.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks.  I was a bit hesitant to make it too general, and would still probably prefer your solution, since having any non-"%", non-digit characters might be a sign that something isn't really a percentage after all.  Thus having an NA returned might be preferable to having it return something sensible.

Comment: As you said, for a more general function your solution would be preferable. But than it would be called percentChar2numeric() or something and the OP would have to problem with the complexity (which would be hidden in the function).

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to convert an entire column and combined the above answers.

```
pct_to_number<- function(x){
  x_replace_pct<-sub("%", "", x)
  x_as_numeric<-as.numeric(x_replace_pct)
  }
df[['ColumnName']] = pct_to_number(df[['ColumnName']])
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor! Modified my response.

Comment: I added a `/ 100` at the end of the third line to get proper float values.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
> x = "10%"
> as.numeric(substr(x,0,nchar(x)-1))
[1] 10
```

This works also with decimals:

```
> x = "10.1232%"
> as.numeric(substr(x,0,nchar(x)-1))
[1] 10.1232
```

The idea is that the symbol `%` is always at the end of the string.