# Converting percentage to decimal with parse_number?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

`parse_number` has been the perfect function for when I am parsing html tables that have columns formatted with "%".  Very often, I want to use `parse_number` and convert to a decimal in one whole operation.  I know there are alternate ways to parse the function without using `parse-number`, but does `parse_number` have a way to do what I'm looking for built into the function?  Otherwise, most of my `mutate_at` commands end up getting run in two separate operations.

Sample code below:

```
library(readr)

x <- "10.5%"

parsed <- parse_number(x)

parsed_decimal <- parsed / 100
```

Comment: You could directly do `parse_number(x)/100` ? Also here are variety of options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329059/how-to-convert-character-of-percentage-into-numeric-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write your own function:

```r
x <- "10.5%"
y <- c("9.0%", "8.3%", "51.2%")

parse_pct <- function(x) {
    parsed <- readr::parse_number(x)
    parsed_decimal <- parsed / 100
    parsed_decimal
}

parse_pct(x)
#> [1] 0.105
purrr::map_dbl(y, parse_pct)
#> [1] 0.090 0.083 0.512
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The function is a good idea, but you've written a vectorised function so no need to map over it and introduce another dependency in purrr. Just `parse_pct(y)` does it.