# Make a list of char (percents) ints

Tags: r

I have a 2D list that has two columns containing percentages of data I am collecting. Because the data is scraped, the whole list is of type character. I've tried `gsub("%", "", mydata[[5]][2])` which turns that column into 9 rows of c('2', '11', '13'...) and then `as.numeric(myurl[[5]][2])` but then I get NAs by coercion. If I try to call `as.numeric(myurl[[5]][2])` first, I get "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'".

Edit: Here is the result of using `sub("%", "", myurl[[5]][2])` 
[As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF4fs.jpg) they're not ints and they are not formatting how I would like them to. The [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5v2Y.jpg) is just a column that looks fine but acts up when I try to use them numerically.

Comment: It would be easier to comment on the problem if we see sample data that produces some good and some bad results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert character of percentage into numeric in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329059/how-to-convert-character-of-percentage-into-numeric-in-r)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, it formats it into the image I added above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of what the data looks like? Sounds like `str_remove(.,"%")` and `separate()` to break your list into multiple columns would work.